# Add extra whitespace between heading and enumeration

Tags: spacing

[image]

I would like to add some additional vertical white space between the heading text and the enumeration items.

Not sure what the best way is to do this. After doing some searching, have not found a clear or simple way to do this.

```
\begin{center}
    {\textbf{\Large MATHS 254 ASSIGNMENT 1}}

    NAME HERE - ID HERE
\end{center}

\begin{enumerate}[itemsep=100pt]
```

Comment: You can use `\title{Your title}` and in the `\maketitle` in the article.

Comment: @TeddyvanJerry I was using that before, but didn't want the date.

Comment: Use `\date{}` to remove the date.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Regularly, using the `\maketitle` thing is better than manually building the format.
If you do not want the date, use `\date{}` to remove it.

Use the following MWE:

```tex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{nicematrix}
\title{\bfseries MATHS 254 ASSIGNMENT 1}
\author{NAME HERE -- ID HERE}
\date{} % <-- remove date

\begin{document}
    \maketitle
    (1) $v_1=[P_1]_B=\begin{bNiceArray}{c}1\\2\\3\end{bNiceArray}$, balabala
\end{document}
```

which yields
[image: Result]